# How to replace or remove this list of spaces (<br>'s)

Tags: html, replace

I have a situation here, I would like to replace or remove this etra spaces (br tags) I'm readying a txt file and providing 
 for each line but it has it has some extra empty spaces, the final result is this>

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />  
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />Propiedades y usos del abedul
<br />
<br />
<br />Abedul - Betula alba
<br />Alamo Blanco- Arbol de la sabiduria - Biezo
<br />
<br />===========================================================================
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br />
<br />Son muchas las aplicaciones de este elegante arbol. Su madera, y sobre
<br />todo su carbon, son excelentes. Su corteza es impermeable, y con ella los
<br />pastores de anta&ntilde;o fabricaban vasos, y hasta polainas para la nieve.
<br />
<br />Habitat: se da en las monta&ntilde;as del norte de Espa&ntilde;a y de Europa, y en el
<br />Canada donde forma extensos bosques, asi como en otras zonas frias y
<br />monta&ntilde;osas del continente americano.
<br />Descripcion: arbol esbelto de hoja caduca, de la familia de las
<br />Betulaceas. Destaca en los bosques por la blancura de su corteza, que se
<br />desprende en finas laminas. Sus ramas jovenes son colgantes, de ahi el
<br />nombre de Betula pendula, y con peque&ntilde;os nodulos o verrugas, de donde le
<br />viene otro de sus
<br />
<br />
<br />nombres cientificos: Betula verrucosa. Ofrece flores masculinas y
<br />femeninas en el mismo arbol.
<br />
<br />Partes utilizadas: las hojas, las yemas, la savia y la corteza.
<br />
<br />Propiedades e indicaciones:  las hojas y las yemas de abedul contienen
<br />sobre todo flavonoides (miricitrina e hiperosido), que le confieren un
<br />notable efecto diuretico (eliminacion de liquidos) y tambien principios
<br />amargos, taninos catequicos y aceite esencial.
<br />En edemas ayuda a eliminar los liquidos retenidos en el organismo,
<br />especialmente en caso de insuficiencia renal o cardiaca. A diferencia de
<br />otros diureticos quimicos, las infusiones de hojas de abedul no provocan
<br />la perdida de grandes cantidades de sales minerales con la orina, ni
<br />irritan los tejidos del ri&ntilde;on. Por el contrario, son capaces de
<br />regenerarlo y desinflamarlo, haciendo disminuir la eliminacion de
<br />albumina con la orina en casos de nefrosis e insuficiencia renal.
<br />Se usan tambien con exito en el sindrome premenstrual. Tomando esa tisana
<br />durante los dias precedentes a la regla, aumenta el volumen de orina y
<br />disminuye la hinchazon de los tejidos, especialmente en piernas, vientre
<br />y mamas.
<br />Para tratar los calculos renales las infusiones de hojas y yemas de
<br />abedul facilitan la eliminacion de las arenillas de la orina e impiden
<br />que se formen calculos renales. Se ha podido comprobar que, en algunos
<br />casos, pueden incluso disolverlos. El uso de la infusion se halla
<br />indicado tanto durante el ataque de colico nefritico (de ri&ntilde;on), como de
<br />forma continuada para evitar la formacion de calculos.
<br />Como depurativo las hojas y yemas de abedul poseen un efecto depurativo
<br />sobre las sustancias toxicas que recargan la sangre, como el acido urico.
<br />De ahi que las tisanas preparadas con ellas resulten altamente
<br />beneficiosas en caso de gota o artritismo.
<br />Su uso por via interna resulta indicado para limpiar la piel de impurezas
<br />en casos de eccemas cronicos y celulitis.
<br />En aplicacion externa, por medio de compresas, las hojas y yemas poseen
<br />accion antiseptica y cicatrizante sobre llagas y heridas, debido a los
<br />taninos que contienen.
<br />La corteza del abedul, como la del sauce y la de la quina, tiene
<br />propiedades febrifugas. Se toma en decoccion para bajar la fiebre. Al
<br />principio de la primavera, antes de que salgan las hojas, serrandole una
<br />rama o pinchandole el tronco, el abedul puede proporcionar cada dia
<br />varios litros de deliciosa savia. Esta savia tiene las mismas propiedades
<br />que hemos descrito para las hojas, pero ademas constituye una agradable
<br />bebida. Las aldeanas del norte de Europa la toman para disfrutar de un
<br />cutis tan blanco y limpio como la corteza del arbol.
<br />
<br />Uso: internamente, en infusion de 20 a 50 grs. de hojas y/o yemas por
<br />litro de agua. Se puede tomar hasta un litro diario. Como resulta un poco
<br />amarga, conviene endulzarla con miel o azucar moreno. La adicion de 1
<br />gramo de bicarbonato sodico aumenta la eficacia de la tisana de abedul,
<br />pues sus principios activos se disuelven mejor en medio alcalino. Tambien
<br />en decoccion de corteza, de 50 a 80 gramos por litro de agua; hervir
<br />hasta que se reduzca a la mitad y tomar 2 o 3 tazas diarias endulzadas
<br />con miel.
<br />La savia se ingiere diluida en agua (al 50%) a modo de bebida
<br />refrescante. Hay que evitar que fermente. Para uso externo, en compresas
<br />sobre la piel que se realizan con la misma infusion que se ha descrito
<br />para uso interno.
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />   
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

But I dont know how to remove all the first brs and all the end brs with replace is not working.

and this is not working

`str_replace("<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />","",$string)`

The situation here is that I want to save it on a data base so I want to remove those brs to leave space in my data base, since i don't need them and I have more than 1000 txt files like this :S

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your CSS file or style tag

`div p,
div br {
    display: inline;
}`

Heres a [Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ax/)

Else, make a CSS class or id which works on specific br

Comment: I have tried with that, but any result. I need basically to replace them since I'm going to save mor than 1000 records in a db with same format

Comment: If there are so many files I can think of only one way use regex on linux command line. Because that is what I do for bulk editing. But you may find another way around.

Comment: [Try this Link](http://cybernetnews.com/find-replace-multiple-files/). I just found it on google, I haven't tried it

Comment: Hi, I can't use that, since I need to replace it using php since in the same function I will do an Insert to mysql for more than 1000 files in a loop.

Comment: How would anyone know you need to use PHP if you do not write that on your post? Put what exactly you need by editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this:

$getNewStr = fgets($file1)."
";
....

```
if(strlen($getNewStr)<9){
    $getNewStr = substr($getNewStr,7);
}
```

since it go line by line reading the txt file I have added that, and it works xD